# Reinforce foldable table legs

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-analysis, applied-mechanics, stresses, structures

I'm trying to build a table with 4 swivel legs that can be locked into arbitrary angles so that it can stand over one to three rows of storage crates in my garage:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the legs aren't reinforced or braced to prevent wobbling or shaking. In fact, the fixtures to the table top are simply pipe flanges which might sustain too much stress on their own:

[image]

If the maximum load is 100kg, will this design be adequate? I'd appreciate any advice on improving the structural integrity.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am 68 kilograms and you could never convince me to sit on this!

let's say the table is 90cm high and the legs can extend out, by just eyeballing and correct me please, 50cm. and your lege ar 2cm pipe and the screws are on a 3cm diameter circle.

One can not carefully place the load at the center of the table every time, also because of the fact the legs are in the way, they got banged up a few times and the screws holding the flanges come loose.

So considering the built-in wobbliness and bad wearing out the table is not even holding level.

then you put a load of 100 kg on an off-center point and shaky legs give into a wobble and let the load effectively impacts with a dynamic load of 250 kg near one of the corners.

$$\Sigma M=0\quad 250kg* 0.5m/ 0.015m_{flange\ radius}=833kg\ pullout\ force\ on\ screws$$
Not good!

Comment: But if you welded a frame with a sleeve to the legs below the table the flange screws would never see a pullout force.

Comment: @DDuck Wouldn't the clearance between the sleeve and the leg cause pullout forces on the flange screws though?